# Communication between two Forms C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have three forms, the main form which it's calling the Form2 and the Form2 has the Form3 as constructor and same thing for the Form3 (constructor of the Form2).

In fact, I'm trying to put information of the Form3 in the Form2.

I have a DataGridView with information (Form2) and I want to put information at the opening of the Form3 in the Textboxes.

I can make this but I also want by opening the Form3 sending information to the Form2 to create a new row in my DataGridView (Form2) after closing the Form3.

In my Main Form :

```cpp
        private void btn_gestCapteur_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FormGestionCapteurs fGesCapt;
            fGesCapt = new FormGestionCapteurs();

            FormGestionCapteurs fGestCapt;
            fGestCapt = new FormGestionCapteurs(fConfRes, new FormAjoutCapteur(fConfRes,fGesCapt));
            fGestCapt.ShowDialog();
        }
```

In my Form1 which it's called FormGestionCapteurs :

```cs
        FormAjoutCapteur fAddCpt;

        FormConfigReseau fConfRes;

        public FormGestionCapteurs(FormConfigReseau fConfRes, FormAjoutCapteur fAddCpt)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.fConfRes = fConfRes;

            this.fAddCpt = fAddCpt;
        }

        public FormGestionCapteurs()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

In my Form3 which it's called FormAjoutCapteurs :

```cs
        FormGestionCapteurs fGest;

        FormConfigReseau fConfRes;

        public FormAjoutCapteur(FormConfigReseau fConfRes, FormGestionCapteurs fGest)
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.fConfRes = fConfRes;

            this.fGest = fGest;
        }

        private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)fGest.tab_listeCapteurs.Rows[0].Clone(); //fGest. is the Form2 and tab_listeCapteurs is the DataGridView
                    row.Cells[0].Value = txtBox_name.Text; //These textboxes aren't empty so I want to send the text of these in the good cells of my DataGridView
                    row.Cells[1].Value = txtBox_marque.Text;
                    row.Cells[2].Value = txtBox_model.Text;
                    row.Cells[3].Value = numUpDown_calibre.Value;
                    row.Cells[4].Value = txtBox_a.Text;
                    row.Cells[5].Value = txtBox_b.Text;
                    fGest.tab_listeCapteurs.Rows.Add(row);
                    //This code doesn't effect
        }
```

I can send information of the DataGridView at the Form3 but when I want to create a new row in the Form2 after closing the Form3 it doesn't insert the row.

Comment: What is the "Form1" for? it looks no meaning. are you asking: how to update Form2 on Form3 closed?

Comment: Your last sentence in your question is confusing.  So you want to send data from Form3 to Form2?

Comment: May I suggest you create a class that contains all the data for each row in the grid and then pass this class instance to the forms to populate the text cells. Preferably using data binding.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that by using the delegates. i can barely understand your problem but i am sure this will help.
just Modify the Code according to your need.

```
public partial class Form3 : Form
{
    public delegate void callback_data(string dataToSend);
    public event callback_data sentIt;


   private void form3_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
   {
       string data = "Top Secret Data";
       sentIt(data);
   }
}
```

Now in your Form2 Where you are Creating instance of Form3 call the Event.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

   private void Form2_OnLoad()
   {
       Form2 obj = new Form2();
       obj.sentIt += onReceiveData;
       obj.ShowDialog();
   }

   private void onReceiveData(string myData)
   {
      console.WriteLine(myData);
   }
}
```

In this way you will get the data from Form3 to Form2 ..
i have tried 200 new techniques :p but this delegates is the most efficient way of doing this! Trust me.

Answer (score 0):

A quick answer, see comments inside code. but it looks "Form1" in not useful for your question.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    //No need to use constructor, this is good for a frequently open/close child form.
    private readonly FormAjoutCapteur formAjoutCapteur = new FormAjoutCapteur();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        formAjoutCapteur.FormClosed += FormAjoutCapteur_FormClosed; //this is simplest way to get inputs
        //formAjoutCapteur.BtnOK.Click += FormAjoutCapteur_BtnOK_Click; //this require the button's "Modifiers" must be "Public"
    }

    private void FormAjoutCapteur_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        var text = formAjoutCapteur.textBoxInput.Text;//you can simply change the input "modifiers" as "public"
        //var obj = formAjoutCapteur.GetInputs(); // you can make a public method to return all input into an object, which is recommended.

        //add your row
        this.dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    }

    private void BtnGestionCapteurs_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        formAjoutCapteur.ShowDialog(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you have is master/detail form situation. .NET Framework has a lot of built-in functionality to deal with this sort of thing. I really do not understand the details of the request, so this might be vaguely helpful to you. I also suggest you read a book or take a class on Data Binding as it is going to make your life so much easier than manually updating textbox by textbox and moving data around manually.

## Part A - Master View

First create a data model to represent each row in your datagrid. From the posting I assumed the following data model:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines a Capteurs
/// </summary>
public class Capteurs : ICloneable
{
    public Capteurs()
    {
        this.Name=  string.Empty;
        this.Marque=  string.Empty;
        this.Model=  string.Empty;
        this.Calibre=  0;
        this.A=  string.Empty;
        this.B=  string.Empty;
    }
    public Capteurs(Capteurs other)
    {
        this.Name = other.Name;
        this.Marque = other.Marque;
        this.Model = other.Model;
        this.Calibre= other.Calibre;
        this.A=other.A;
        this.B=other.B; 
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Marque { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Calibre { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }

    #region ICloneable Members
    public Capteurs Clone() => new Capteurs(this);
    object ICloneable.Clone() => Clone();
    #endregion

}
```

Noticed I implemented `ICloneable` in order to make copies of the data so I do not disturb in master list unless I want to.

Next I added a data source to the project based in this class

[image: add data source]

The master form contains a `DataGridView` to show all the data that is linked to a data source

[image: data link]

Now when the form loads, I add data to the data source with `capteursBindingSource.DataSource  = list;` and the list of items shows up on the master form.

[image: master form]

Add the following properties to the master form in order to have access to the currently selected item, the list manager, the list of items and the index of the current item.

```
public Capteurs Current
{
    get => List[Index];
    set => List[Index] = value;
}
public CurrencyManager CurrencyManager 
{ 
    get => BindingContext[capteursBindingSource] as CurrencyManager; 
}
public IList<Capteurs> List 
{ 
    get => capteursBindingSource.DataSource as IList<Capteurs>; 
}
public int Index
{
    get => BindingContext[capteursBindingSource].Position;
    set => BindingContext[capteursBindingSource].Position = value;
}
```

## Part B - Detail View

Create a second form and drag the data source onto the surface of the form

[image: data as details]

[image: drag and drop]

Delete the positioning toolbar (since you are only displaying one set of data at a time). Organize the controls that get created and add buttons for OK/Cancel or Accept/Close or something to indicate if the edits are good or not.

[image: detail form]

Finally, add the following property in order to get or set the data to be shown in the form

```
public Capteurs Current
{
    get => BindingContext[capteursBindingSource].Current as Capteurs;
    set => capteursBindingSource.DataSource = new Capteurs[] { value };
}
```

## Part C - Linking the forms

All of the above is done in order to simplify the transfer of data between forms. In the master form the following button handler opens up the detail form, send a clone of the current data and if the user selects [Keep] the edited data is stored back into the master list *and the grid is refreshed* using the `CurrencyManager.Refresh()` command.

```
private void detailsButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dlg = new DetaillForm();
    dlg.Current = this.Current.Clone();

    if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        this.Current = dlg.Current;
        CurrencyManager.Refresh();
    }
}
```

[image: the final result]

Comment: It's good effort, but come on, it's out of box! what you should do is to details what the question exactly is, but not spending a day to give a replacement solution. and his question is not answered: how to transfer values between forms? but you give him more questions: what is the magic of bindings between forms? what to do if he want to validate details form with this solution? how to bind if data table is not same as grid view? and so on...

Comment: I think the question is answered by `dlg.Current = this.Current.Clone();` which is how values get transferred from one form to another. Also this `C#`, but the _OP_  doesn't have a data model. I thought that was the wrong approach, and my answer points towards a better solution strategy.